# Intersect a line considering the topological direction

Tags: postgis, topology, st-intersects

I have a set of lines in postgis, and  I want to intersects those lines which only go from point A to point B. And I don't want those lines which go from point B to point A. So, my question is : how I set in my query the topological direction ?

Comment: WHERE ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(LInestring), point_a) where point_a is the geometry representing point A, obviously. This is how I would do it as a standard Postgis ST_Intersects query. If you are asking about doing it with Topology functions, please update the question to make that clear.